# Updating ARIMA model

Tags: estimation, multiple-regression, forecasting, arima

My question is about updating the parameters of a regression with ARIMA errors model 
as new (monthly) data becomes available each month. 
Similar question were asked here before:

- [Updating ARIMA models at frequent intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34139/updating-arima-models-at-frequent-intervals)
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52131/how-to-update-forecasts-in-an-arima-model
- [What do you consider a new model versus an updated model (time series)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57745/what-do-you-consider-a-new-model-versus-an-updated-model-time-series)

My concern is, when do I know (or how can I test) that my model structure (ARMA terms, exogenous variables) is still suitable? Say in the simplest case my model is 
y = const + b*x + e, where e ~ ARIMA
I estimated in my fitting sample b=-3.
A new data point (of the next month) is available and I re-fit the model and obtain 
b = -3.5 
and so on.

**When do I know, that something is wrong or how can I continuously (with each update) test my model for consistency?**

I know, that the Chow-Test a useful test for model stability. But I always have only one data-point to update.

My idea is:

- Check each month the one-step-ahead forecast with the actual value. If the model gives still reasonable results -> keep it.
- Collect 6 new monthly data points (so half yearly) and check with a Chow-test the model stability between the initial fit-sample and the new sample (6 monthly data points).

Comment: Possibly related questions, though not necessarily answers to all your questions: [\[1\]](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52131/how-to-update-forecasts-in-an-arima-model) [\[2\]](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34139/updating-arima-models-at-frequent-intervals) [\[3\]](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9512/how-to-update-arima-forecast-in-r)